# What does Erkenntnisgewissen mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, dictionary

In Weyl's *Raum. Zeit. Materie.*(see [here](https://ia902604.us.archive.org/18/items/raumzeitmateriev00weyl/raumzeitmateriev00weyl_bw.pdf) for example) In the introduction one can read (italic and bold is not original)

> [...] auf die philosophische werde ich nur ganz nebenher eingehen, aus
>   dem einfachen Grunde, weil in dieser Richtung etwas irgendwie
>   Endgültiges bisher nicht vorliegt und ich selber auch nicht imstande
>   bin, auf die hergehörigen erkenntnistheoretischen Fragen solche
>   Antworten zu geben, *die ich vor meinem **Erkenntnisgewissen** voll
>   verantworten könnte*. [...]

How do you translate the emphasized piece? I am interested especially in the meaning of the word "Erkenntnisgewissen".

Here what I have found.

- Google translates it as *knowledge conscience*
- In the Russian edition of that book it stands as *познавательная совесть* which I don't sure I am able to translate into English correctly
- It seems that there is a word *Erkenntnisgewinn* but it is slightly different

I think that's very important piece of the text so "overdetailed" description would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Weyl says he cannot answer the epistemological questions which may come up, because he feels unable to justify them with the knowledge he has.

The reason why he choses *Erkenntnisgewissen* instead of *Erkenntnis* is he wants to use the phrase

> …, die ich vor meinem Gewissen voll verantworten könnte.

That's a testimony. He cannot testify for or against the epistemology with his knowledge.

The reason why he choses *Erkenntnisgewissen* instead of *Gewissen* is there is no one who demanded him to testify. It's a dilution of the general conscience needed for a testimony.